# Tracking Page Views on dynamic website

Tags: php, dynamic, view, html, counter

I'm trying to store the number of views on a certain post in my database. For example, I have one page index.php, and depending on which article the user clicks on, it will take them to a certain article (still on index.php): index.php?article_id=24. The problem I'm trying to figure out is how do I store a dynamic page that uses php $_GET method to view posts/articles. I can do it on the index.php page, but I can't figure out how to do it on each article, since it's technically still on the same page (index.php).

This is my page counter code:

```
?php
$filename = "pageviews.txt";

$data = file_get_contents($filename);
settype($data,"integer");
$data++;
$f = fopen($filename,"w+");

fwrite($f,$data);
fclose($f);

//insert $data into db
?>
```

And this is my code for after a user clicks on an article and I retrieve the article id:

```
            <section class="large-12 columns">
                <?php 
                    $inner_article = mysqli_fetch_array(query($art_sql));
                    ?>
                    <h1><?php echo $inner_article['art_title']; ?></h1>
                    <img src="<?php echo $inner_article['art_feature_image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $inner_article['art_description']; ?>">
                    <p><?php echo $inner_article['art_create']; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo html_entity_decode($inner_article['art_content']); ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $inner_article['art_tags']; ?></p>
            </section>
```

Now, my last question is whether this is a good approach to storing page views because I have one txt file. How can I store more than one number of page views (for each article) in one txt file. This is why I was thinking using php cookie is a better route.

Comment: Why would you count the page both in a text file and in a DB? And what problems are you specifically having in inserting the `article_id` value into the database? Also, you might want to think bigger than just having a counter in your database.  Why not add a row to the DB for each page request along with a timestamp, that way you can do more advanced queries against the data (requests per day, requests for certain days of the week or hours of the day).  This will allow you to see trends, not just raw numbers.

Comment: Why use a txt file? You've already got an open connection to the database - why not use that instead?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking, but how would you write the code to retrieve the page views if I don't store it in a file first?

Comment: @tickerll Why do you think you need to store it in a file first? What can you do in that file that you can't do in a database?

Comment: @Mike Brant, I'm not having any problems inserting into the database. The problem I'm having is counting page views of each article index.php?article=#. Right now, I can make the counter work only on index.php and not index.php?article=#

Comment: @tickerll And why is that?  You have a value for `$_GET['article_id']` that is all you really need (or even just the entire URI in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`).  What more do you think you need?

Comment: Ah, so do you mean get the uri with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] and store the number of page views into db based on how many times the link was clicked? I guess I'm having trouble making the connections and seeing how I can write the code as I'm quite new to PHP.

Comment: @tickerll - all you need to do is get the article_id; if that article_id doesn't have a row in your database's `pageview` table, create a line for it with a pageview of 1. If it does, increment the existing value. That will increment the page view every time someone looks at a page. If you want more advanced statistics, as MikeBrant mentioned, store a separate row in the table for each pageview, and you can then query the database to get whatever statistics out that you need.

Comment: Hey andrewsi, thanks for your help! I was able to figure it out with much glee. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a count field to your post in DB, and while displaying the article, update this field with a count

```
UPDATE myTable SET Column1=Column1+1
```